# How to prevent 555 timer interference

Tags: 555

I made a triple PWM motor controller with a 555 timer hooked up to 3 IRF621 MOSFETS to the motors. I am having interference troubles. When I turn one knob up, the other motor wants to change speed a small amount, and it is not stable. I added a 47pf capacitor from pin 5 to ground on each, but that didn't seem to help. Is there a way around this, or is that just how the 555 timer is? Here is the schematic I made (yes I know it is a very bad schematic).[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's why people hate the 666 timer chip.  It is from the devil!  :)  It is also unstable or unusable in many applications due to it's variability.  Other than possibly people making super cheap toys, no professional EE that I know of uses 666 timer chips.

Comment: I cant find the datasheet of the 666 anywhere :( they are probably too embarrassed to put data on it

Comment: I designed a clone of the LM666.  Here are the design files, with pics:  http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:92778

Comment: Oh cool, so that was you! I saw it earlier!!

Comment: Guilty as charged.

Comment: I'm wondering how this circuit works at all. Doesn't there need to be a resistor between Vcc and the DIS pin, in order to charge the cap during the charge portion of the cycle?

Comment: Oh yeah, That was my bad, I forgot to draw the resistor in. Dumb me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I notice from your circuit that the 555 and motors are running from a common (5V) power supply without any form of decoupling. The 555 is a current hog and draws a surge of current from the supply every time its output changes.

Try putting a large electrolytic (say 220uF) and a 0.1uf (helps with high frequencies) across each the Vcc and ground pin of the three 555s.

I would also make the capacitor at pin 5 a bit bigger (say 0.1uF) - its job is to smooth out any noise of the internal divider chain of 5K resistors. 47pF is way too low.

[image]